# How can I make a view get bigger again, as soon as the status bar goes back to normal height after a phone call?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

In the simulator I went to Hardware menu and activated the simulation of bigger status bar during phone call.

Now, I tried to make a view in my nib that takes up the whole screen. As soon as the status bar gets smaller, I want my view to get bigger, so it uses that space up there.

But regardless of any autoresizing settings, my view will keep pressed down after that status bar gets smaller. There is a empty slot left where the status bar was after hanging up the call.

What's that actually supposed to be? Is my app recognizing the status bar as a view, or is the status bar indeed making my screen smaller? I mean...does it mess around with my views as if it was a view itself, or do my views not know about a status bar, but about a smaller screen size when the status bar gets bigger?

How do you get your views big again when the status bar returns to normal height?

Comment: What do you mean, "regardless of any autoresizing settings"? What, specifically, are the autoresizing settings on the view you want to expand? (Note that any superviews of that view also have to be autoresizing properly, or you may run into trouble.)

Comment: I missed the superview, as I believed it was a kind of window. After setting autoresizing there, it worked. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

```
[view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

or if that doesn't work

```
[view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```